# xpages href computed in javascript

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have an `<a>` tag which I'm using to redirect the user to another xpage.

Its href property is:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://serv/MyBase.nsf">
```

I use a simple view listing a doc. which contains the server and the name of the application.

So, I want to use some `@DbLookup` function in javascript to get into 2 var the above server and app name:

```
var server = @Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName(), "myVw", 1);

var name = @Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName(), "myVw", 2);

var concat = server+"/"+name;

return concat;
```

How can I compute the `href` property to return the concat variable?

Comment: Where are you using this?  is this in a link control, or html that you are generating yourself?

Comment: also, I believe I see an error where @DbName is missing the parenthesis.  By not typing : "@DbName()", you are not getting any value, and server and name will be empty, if you are not getting errors to begin with.

Comment: Thanks @Greg. it was a typo

Comment: Also, use caution, Some applications are configured to use a custom URL rather than the http(s)://server/path URL.  Although I do not know of any reason why it shouldnt work, it might be a wiser idea to have your view already configured to have the URL and not have to compute it in javascript, not to mention a potential (although minimal) performance optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Link control `xp:link` and calculate the URL in attribute `value`:

```
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var server .... }]]></xp:this.value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Knut's approach is correct, but your code isn't :-). For every XPages load (or refresh) you do 4 `@DbLookup`. You can do a set of optimisations here:

1. Combine the result you want in the view itself, so you only need one lookup
2. Cache the value in the session (or application scope)

something like this (add nice error handling):

```
if (sessionScope.myHref) {
    // Actually do nothing here
} else {
   sessionScope.myHref = @Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName(), "myVw", 3);
}

return sessionScope.myHref;
```

The 3rd column would have the concatenation in the view already. That little snippet does a lookup only once per session. If it is the same for all users, use the applicationScope then it is even less.